# Eureka Swift: Dismiss Controller for MultipleSelectorRow

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I have the following code:

```
form.last! <<< MultipleSelectorRow<String>() {
                $0.title = field.question
                $0.options = []
                for option in field.answers {
                    $0.options.append(option.answer)
                }
            }.onPresent {
                    from, to in
                // TODO FIX
                to.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: from, action: #selector(InputVC.multipleSelectorDone(_:)))
            }
```

Which should add a MultipleSelectorRow that - if clicked - pops another VC and shows some options. Once at least one option is clicked, it should show the "done" button and be able to go back. The button is not appearing, even tho i took the code from the official example.

What did i miss here or do i need to do in order to be able to dismiss the popped Field?

Thanks :)

The multipleSelectorDone function is as follows:

```
func multipleSelectorDone(_ item: UIBarButtonItem) {
        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same feature for a project and found this question. If someone needs here is the solution with Swift 4.2

```
<<< MultipleSelectorRow<String>() {
    $0.title = "Subjects"
    $0.selectorTitle = "Choose"
    $0.options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
    $0.tag = "subjectTypes"
}.onPresent { from, to in
    to.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: from, action: #selector(self.multipleSelectorDone(_:)))
}
```

And multipleSelectorDone method is:

```
@objc func multipleSelectorDone(_ sender:Any?) {
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```